# How can i reduce the time for function location.reload()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reload

I'm using `window.location.reload()` in my `onClick()` function but it's taking too much time to reload so how i can reduce the time for reloading the content.I have already modified reload call as `window.location.reload(true)` so that it will not use cache but still it's taking too much time.Actually, problem is on `location.reload()` it's not refreshing, it's reload the whole content.Can anyone help??

Comment: `so that it will not use cache` - that makes the load process **longer** - have you tried optimising your page for faster (apparent) load times? there's many tricks to make the page at least appear to load faster, to do with where you put script tags, combining scripts together ... and combining CSS - there are so many variables to what makes a page load slow that without a lot more information, all you'll get is speculation

Comment: with cache also it's taking too much time!!

Comment: see "too much time" means nothing - how long does it take? how long is a reload compared to initial load? have you identified any slow loading resources (scripts, css, images etc)

Comment: `it's not refreshing, it's reload the whole content` yes, that's what a reload does

Comment: Dude, real problem is on reload it's just reloading the content i knew freind but i don't want to show to user that it's reloading or refresh !!

Comment: Then I'm afraid you'd need a hypnotist rather than coding help ...

Comment: timings ... how long is initial load ... how long is refresh ... check the network tab of developer tools to see where the bottlenecks are as far as network goes ... check the performance tab for other performance information - not much else I can say

Comment: Meh ... "Refreshing" is essentially the same as "reloading", the question doesn't make sense. Please elaborate your question.

Comment: whenever i'm calling location.reload() it's reloading that's fine but it should not display or user should not aware of that onclick it's refreshing or reloading the content!! that's the problem friends..

Comment: No teemu.. nothing like that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
  function onFunctionClick(getURL){
    window.location=getURL;
  }
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <button onclick="onFunctionClick('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44795125/how-can-i-reduce-the-time-for-function-locatio-reload')"> Refresh </button>
</html>
```

```
<script>
  function onFunctionClick(getURL){
    window.location=getURL;
  }
```

```
<html>
   <button onclick="onFunctionClick('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44795125/how-can-i-reduce-the-time-for-function-locatio-reload')"> Refresh </button>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please also explain, how this snippet makes reloading a page faster?

Comment: I tries yar vishnu this one not working!! yar on reload it should not show the refresh view or reload view

Comment: U don't have to bother teemu the noober

Comment: Dear @Lars Beck I think we cannot change the execution time speed of an onclick event , rather than you can specify it outside of document ready. Then what is your need with reload / refresh. location.reload will reloads the entire page for once.

Comment: Still it's giving me one more way to execute!!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `window.location.reload()` now  I'm using `history.go(0)` which is much smoother and faster than first one reload() call. And the most important thing is that page is not going blank on this reload() call so it solved my problem.Thanks a lots everyone for you responses!!